# Win10 pro, avast doing DNS-request, I tested avast like 3 years ago and removed it as I did not need it anymore, still it's doing DNS-requests

Tags: windows-10, dns, avast

I have this odd problem, is this OK traffic below?

Log from my dns(Unbound&Pihole):
192.168.1.108 is my win10-pc.

Don't even remember, when I used Avast..

```
Jun 25 22:46:21 dnsmasq[678]: reply ip-info.ns1.ff.avast.com is 5.62.38.20
Jun 25 22:46:21 dnsmasq[678]: reply ip-info.ns1.ff.avast.com is 5.62.38.21
Jun 25 22:46:21 dnsmasq[678]: query[A] ip-info.ff.avast.com from 192.168.1.108
Jun 25 22:46:21 dnsmasq[678]: cached ip-info.ff.avast.com is <CNAME>
Jun 25 22:46:21 dnsmasq[678]: cached ip-info.ns1.ff.avast.com is 5.62.38.21
Jun 25 22:46:21 dnsmasq[678]: cached ip-info.ns1.ff.avast.com is 5.62.38.20
Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: query[A] emupdate.avcdn.net from 192.168.1.10

Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: query[A] ccleaner.tools.avcdn.net from 192.168.1.108
Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: forwarded ccleaner.tools.avcdn.net to 127.0.0.1

Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: forwarded ccleaner.tools.avcdn.net to 127.0.0.1
Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: reply ccleaner.tools.avcdn.net is <CNAME>
Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: reply tools.avcdn.net.edgesuite.net is <CNAME>
Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: reply a1163.dscd.akamai.net is 62.183.170.121
Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: query[A] ccleaner.tools.avcdn.net from 192.168.1.108
Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: cached ccleaner.tools.avcdn.net is <CNAME>
Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: cached a1163.dscd.akamai.net is 62.183.170.105

Jun 25 22:46:22 dnsmasq[678]: query[A] ncc.avast.com from 192.168.1.108

Jun 25 22:46:23 dnsmasq[678]: reply ncc.avast.com.edgesuite.net is <CNAME>
Jun 25 22:46:23 dnsmasq[678]: reply a1488.dscd.akamai.net is 62.183.170.105n
Jun 25 22:46:23 dnsmasq[678]: query[A] analytics.ff.avast.com from 192.168.1.108
Jun 25 22:46:23 dnsmasq[678]: gravity blocked analytics.ff.avast.com is 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have this odd problem, is this OK traffic below?

I personally do not use software by Pitform since they were acquired by Avast.  They were also hacked and distributed literal malicious files for a period of time until they fixed it.  Yes; A security company was compromised to the point that their own software distributed a malicious payload.

If you are worried I would simply uninstall CCleaner.  By removing CCleaner you will remove the unwanted and unwarranted DNS queries to Avast.

Comment: CCleaner is now owned by Avast! In any event, you might be better of using the specific Avast! uninstaller: https://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility .

Comment: Unistalled Ccleaner, thanks for the help.